# Path to Access Database in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2015, datagridview

I'm working on a project in VB.NET, using Visual Studio 2015. My goal is that the user can create contacts, which the program puts in an Access database and lists in a DataGridView. I am using the following connection string:

```
    Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Accustomer\Accustomer\Global.accdb
```

This works fine when I publish it to my own PC, but the problem is that when I try to run it on another PC, it does not work because of the data source path not existing on that PC(pretty logic). I have tried to use "Data Source = Global.accdb". This works for displaying the data, but not for implementing the data into the database. Is there any way that the program recognizes the database without implementing the full path to the database?

Comment: why are you hardcoding the path? construct your path programatically like [project path]\\[db]\Global.accdb

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean? I'm very inexperienced with databases, so I might seem a bit stupid here.. Thanks for the quick reaction anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments by krish,you should "build" your own path...so everytime you run you programm on another machine YOUR CODE creates the path using the right parameters. 
You dont give a fix path, your code creates the right one for every machine it runs on. So the filename can be hardcoded, but the path to it should be "flexible".

In krish example [projectPath] and [db] are variables, that contain the right values depending on the PC.

```
  $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {projectPath}\{db}\Global.accdb"
```

Comment: I've tried to do that, with the following declarations:
`Dim bdir As String = Application.StartupPath`
`Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {bdir}\Global.accdb"`


Now VS comes with the following error:
`C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Accustomer\Accustomer\bin\Debug\bdir\Global.accdb' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly`


I suppose I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

What's presented below has already been mentioned and is correct, here I'm simply showing a full working example.

I created a class named Operations with a public (could be private) variable to create a connection string where the connection points to Global.accdb in the same folder as the application's executable file. If the database were a folder below you would add that path in the IO.Path.Combine right before the hard coded string. Note I used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory as Application.StartupPath is not always available in other types of projects.

Create the connection string.

```
Private Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
{
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
    .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Global.accdb")
}
```

Now here is the full code which I wrote for replying to questions for constructing not only the connection but for read/add/update and delete encapsulated into a single class for simplicity.

```
Public Class Operations
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Points to Global.accdb in the same folder as the application's
    ''' executable file
    ''' </summary>
    Private Builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
    {
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
        .DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Global.accdb")
    }
    Public Sub New()
        If Not IO.File.Exists(Builder.DataSource) Then
            Throw New IO.FileNotFoundException("Failed to find application's database")
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub GetCustomerData()
        Dim DataTable As New DataTable

        Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                cmd.CommandText =
                    <SQL>
                            SELECT Identifier, ContactTitle, Country, CompanyName
                            FROM Customers 
                            ORDER BY CompanyName ASC
                    </SQL>.Value

                cn.Open()
                DataTable.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
    Public Function AddNewRow(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Contact As String, ByRef Identfier As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim Success As Boolean = True
        Dim Affected As Integer = 0

        Try
            Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                    cmd.CommandText =
                        <SQL>
                            INSERT INTO Customer 
                            (
                                CompanyName,
                                ContactName
                            ) 
                            Values
                            (
                                @CompanyName,
                                @ContactName
                            )
                        </SQL>.Value

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", Name)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", Contact)

                    cn.Open()

                    Affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    If Affected = 1 Then
                        cmd.CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
                        Identfier = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Success = False
        End Try

        Return Success

    End Function
    Public Function UpdateCustomer(ByVal CustomerId As Integer, ByVal Name As String, ByVal Contact As String) As Boolean
        Dim Success As Boolean = True
        Dim Affected As Integer = 0

        Try
            Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                    cmd.CommandText =
                        <SQL>
                            UPDATE Customer 
                            SET CompanyName = @CompanyName, ContactName = @ContactName 
                            WHERE Identifier = @Identifier
                        </SQL>.Value

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", Name)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactName", Contact)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Identifier", Contact)

                    cn.Open()

                    Affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    If Affected = 1 Then
                        Success = True
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Success = False
        End Try

        Return Success

    End Function
    Public Function DeleteCustomer(ByVal CustomerId As Integer) As Boolean
        Dim Success As Boolean = True
        Dim Affected As Integer = 0

        Try
            Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE Identifier = @Identifier"

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Identifier", CustomerId)

                    cn.Open()

                    Affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    If Affected = 1 Then
                        Success = True
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Success = False
        End Try

        Return Success

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I'm still having a problem right now, it does not recognize the file from the path. I found out VS does not publish the access DB with the project, and neither does it load when I'm running it without publishing(Debug - any CPU). I have my accessDB file in the `Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Accustomer\Accustomer` map. Is this the right map, and how do I make sure it publishes with the project?